# Laravel 4: I have a route parameter named the same as a folder in my public folder, the route is not getting called

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In Laravel 4,

I have a route defined like this:

```
Route::controller('abc','abc\SomeController');
```

And in my public folder I have this:

```
abc
packages
.htaccess
.project
favicon.ico
index.php
robots.txt
```

If I browse to the route, I get a directory view of the *abc* folder. If I rename the *abc* folder to *xyz*, then my route works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you experience is normal behaviour of web server.
Web server finds actual `abc` folder in your public directory so URL is not redirected to `index.php` but `abc/SomeController` is requested directly (and `SomeController` is not found in `public/abc`)

That's normal behaviour. If server finds that abc folder exists, this URL is not redirected to index.php, but send directly to abc

Comment: I know it is the namespace. Which is why it's working when i rename the public folder.

Comment: The route correctly calls the namespaced controller, if I don't have a folder in my public directory called "abc".

Comment: My public directory is right inside the webroot, while my project folder is outside the webroot. So nothing weird about my public folder either. This one has me stumped!

Comment: That's normal behaviour. If server finds that `abc` folder exists, this URL is not redirected to `index.php`, but send directly to `abc`

Comment: Exactly! :) Are you creating large app? If so, I would pick 2nd option

Comment: I'm already using option 1....which I like for now. I just wanted all my assets in a folder named the same as my namespace. And my route is named the same as my namespace. That's where you pointed out my problem, that I need to work on my .htaccess or something, because it's skipping index.php

Comment: Just update your answer that the abc folder in my public directory is getting called, instead of index.php, that's my problem (not namespacing). And if you have any solution for that, that would be a bonus, but I'll accept your answer either way.

Comment: Done already. No, I don't have any solution. I don't think you can do a thing but rename.